# In excel, how can I edit an existing chart?

Tags: excel

I feel like the answer to this one is going to make me slap my forehead and utter "Duh", but here goes...

I have an Excel spreadsheet that someone else created.  It contains charts that I want to modify, specifically the data source they're using (cells).  But I can't seem to get a handle on the definition of the chart in an editor or anything of that sort.

Instructions I found on-line say all I need do is click the chart to get to a point where I can change things.  But clicking gets me nothing... not left MB, center or right, single or double clicking.

There is a little "+" in a small circle in the top left corner of the chart, but when I click it, I get a message telling me that it's locked and can't be moved.  "Ah-ha", it's locked?  I tried to find out how to unlock it, but no luck.

I went into developer and clicked "View Code" thinking this was a VBA thing.  But there's no code.

Does anyone know who I can determine how the charts were created and how I can modify them ?

As far as ExCel version, I think this is "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus" ?  Does that make any sense ?I can't seem to find anything else that looks like a version.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the sheet is protected and the chart has been locked. Try right clicking the sheet and selecting "Unprotect". It might ask you for a password. If it does, and you no longer have access to the password then you can break in using the VBA editor and the code in the link below.

http://www.excelsupersite.com/how-to-unprotect-an-excel-spreadsheet-if-you-have-lost-your-password/

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Yes, indeed, it appears to be protected.  Right-click didn't give me the option to attempt unprotect, but File -> Protect/Unprotect did.  It is protected by a password, and I'll attempt the procedure(s) i nthe link to get at the definitions.  Thanks Again !